# How to change Android toolbar background color with XML without creating a new toolbar layout

Tags: android

So I have create a theme for the application:

```
<style name="MainApplicationTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:background">@color/light_green</item>
</style>
```

and now the toolbar has same color as main application background. How do I change toolbar's color without creating a new layout for toolbar and without a need to do those code changes in every single activity?

Comment: I posted an answer, but I accidentally pressed delete and then undelete. So, if by any chance it gets deleted let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Activity where you want to change toolbar color you can use this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

This will change the background color to `black`. Or if you want to change it inside your theme, do it like this:

```
<style name="MainApplicationTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:background">@color/light_green</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

This will also change it to black.

Comment: So it appears it is called an 'action bar' also...:)

Comment: The toolbar is the View in android like any other. But with it you can create the actionBar-like layout and use it like ActionBar since it's easier to manipulate than actionBar itself. But the ActionBar is given by the Theme you are using, like in your case. You can always use a Theme that extends NoActionBar and then create your own using Toolbar.